# Why use a view engine?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I'm currently learning both Asp mvc and angularjs separately.

It seems that the razor view engine can do most of the things that angular can render (like rendering a row for each user), but it seems like bad practice to let the server do any processing (rendering in this case).

My question is: why use razor and not serve plain unrendered html?

Answer (score 0):

Razor view and angular operates on 2 different techniques, the Razor engine works in server while angular works on browser.

Certain applications use server rendering due to different reasons, when server rendering is required the Razor engine is one of many way to render html in the server side.

Angular on the other hand works on client side by binding/manipulating html to a model via a controller.

> why use razor and not serve plain unrendered html?

You don't need to use Razor if you design your application to be a full blown SPA. You could get data using web-api and use angular to manipulate views.

Comment: Could you address the reasons for server rendering? I assumed server rendering was bad because the client could also do the work

Comment: It depends on your application, some applications could rely on angular just to bind controller and views, while it could rely on mvc framework to render layouts, menu systems and also authentication.

Comment: How do you decide what to render where though? I assume that when big Web companies like Google develop a Web app they have guidelines as to what operations should be done on the server and what on the client. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It depends on the application, if you are going full SPA all rendering happens in the browser, but if you are Razor without using a lot of JS then most of rendering happens in the server. So it really depends on the tech stack you are using, even in large companies like google the tech stack is not fixed, it is different from product to product.

Answer (score 0):

the razor engine provides a lot of facilities to the developer to write code fast , it provides a great combination (in coding and prformance as well) between plain html and c# , it provides the well known facilities of asp.net like master page (called layout), session state and a lot others , it provides a lot of new facilities as bundles , scaffolding and others, it provide great Intellisense .

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor